# Automatic open Colorbox modal window

Tags: drupal-7, colorbox

I'm using the Colorbox module in Drupal 7. I'm opening an external website. I can make it work with a link. Click [here](http://www.betararetearepublic.com/), then click the "colorbox popup" link at the bottom, middle column. The client would like this to open automatically when the page opens. I've created a block and added the following code (from the colorbox site).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Display a welcome message on first visit, and set a cookie that expires in 30 days:
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') === -1) {
    var expires = new Date();
    expires.setDate(expires.getDate()+30);
    document.cookie = "visited=true; expires="+expires.toUTCString();
    jQuery.colorbox({html:"URL goes here", width:887, height:638});
}
</script>
```

But it does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the DOM is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
// Display a welcome message on first visit, and set a cookie that expires in 30 days:
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') === -1) {
    var expires = new Date();
    expires.setDate(expires.getDate()+30);
    document.cookie = "visited=true; expires="+expires.toUTCString();
    jQuery.colorbox({href:"URL goes here", width:887, height:638});
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the **open** parameter to **true**.

So you can write:

```
jQuery.colorbox({href:"URL goes here", width:887, height:638, open: true});
```

This is documented here:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox